# $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)} = \mathcal{P}(U)\setminus\mathcal{P}(A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to prove $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)} = \mathcal{P}(U)\setminus\mathcal{P}(A)$

Here is what I tried:

$$\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(U)\setminus\mathcal{P}(A)$$

Let $x$ be an element such that:
$$x\in \overline{\mathcal{P}(A)} \implies x \notin \mathcal{P}(A) \implies x \not\subseteq A$$

By that we can conclude by definition of Universal set that $x \subseteq U$ so that means $x \in \mathcal{P}(U)$ so by definition of "set difference":

if $x \in\mathcal{P}(U)$ and $x \notin \mathcal{P}(A) \implies x\in (\mathcal{P}(U)\setminus \mathcal{P}(A) ).$

$$\mathcal{P}(U)\setminus \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{P}(A)}$$

Let $x$ be element such that $x \in (\mathcal{P}(U)\setminus\mathcal{P}(A))$ so by definition of "set difference":

$$x \in \mathcal{P}(U) \text { and } x \notin \mathcal{P}(A)$$

$$x\notin \mathcal{P}(A) \implies x\in\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)}$$

or everything completely wrong and there no such thing and its impossible to define $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)}$ ?

Comment: Instead of writing $x\subsetneq A$ you need to write $x\not\subseteq A$ (`x\not\subseteq A`). This is because $x\subsetneq A$ means that $x$ is a subset of $A$ but not equal to $A$. You don't want that. Otherwise this looks fine to me.

Comment: I have tidied the presentation. Grammar and style have been improved (these things are good to pay attention to) and I have taken a wholistic approach to $\LaTeX$. It never makes sense to keep some of the expression outside the delimiters, and only put the symbols inside. Put the entire expression inside the $\LaTeX$ delimiters.